# The device 'Microsoft DV Camera and VCR' could not be opened

Tags: camera, firewire, capture, sony-vegas, dv

I trying capture video from DV camera into computer with firewire cable. 
When I select "Capture Video", and then check DV, "Sony Video Capture 6.0" pop-up this error:

The device 'Microsoft DV Camera and VCR' could not be opened

[image: Screenshot]

I use Sony Vegas Pro 8.0 and Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. I tried many ways and they was not successful. Camera "Canon MV750i".

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my FireWire-connected video camera being recognized by Sony Vegas and Video Capture. I'm not sure if it is a problem with my configuration but my FireWire devices don't automatically "plug-and-play" like my USB-connected devices.

My solution is to connect the FireWire camera and reboot my computer. Works every time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it was because I was plugging the cable into a front panel FireWire port. Plugged it into the FireWire port on the motherboard's back plate and it was recognised fine.

You could also try using [WinDV](http://windv.mourek.cz/) to test your connection as well.